# Can't read an Ansible fact

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I know accessing Ansible facts is [well documented](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-loop-over-a-list-of-hosts-in-a-group-inside-of-a-template), but I can't get this code to work.

```
# site.yml
---
- name: get fact
  hosts: webservers

  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ hostvars['web01.example.com']['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'] }}"
    - fail:
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
fatal: [web01.example.com] => One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'
```

Yet when I run the command "ansible -i inventory -m setup", I do see the dictionary key:

```
web01.example.com | success >> {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
            "<ip_address>"
        ],
        (other objects...)
    }
}
```

This is my inventory file:

```
# inventory
[webservers]
web01.example.com ansible_host=<ip_address>
```

I also tried the following hostvars setting but I get the same error:

```
hostvars['web01.example.com']['ansible_facts']['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses']
```

What am I doing wrong here?  It seems like this should be pretty easy.

Comment: When you run your playbook, is there actually a "setup" task executed as very first task? `{{ hostvars['web01.example.com']['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'] }}` should work, so should `{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'] }}`. Also `{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}` would be working and since you only have one host is actually the preferred solution. You only need to work with the `hostvars` object if you need to access facts of other hosts. But if all this does not work, it suggests the fact is simply not defined, which only could happen if no setup module is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a little confusing with ansible, but you just use (without `ansible_facts` in the middle):

```
hostvars['web01.example.com']['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses']
```

Or as @oley posted

```
hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses']
```

for the respective host in a task

In documentation you posted it is also always without `ansible_facts` in the middle, but it is just easy to overlook :)

Comment: My blunder was that I had Ansible 'gather_facts' set to False instead of True.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
- debug: msg="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'] }}"
```